Changing variables in sympy
According to the documentation one can make substitutions as:
expr = sin(2*x) + cos(2*x)
expr.subs(sin(2*x), 2*sin(x)*cos(x))

But say x = y + 2. How do I convert the expression from a function of x to a function of y without having to give the substitution explicitly?

You're saying you don't want to do expr.subs(x, y+2)?

That is correct. x = y + 2 is a trivial case. But I want to know if sympy can figure out that x and y are tied via an equation and I want to move from x being my variable to y being my variable.

SymPy offers a module to perform trigonometric simplification. It contains many transformation rules, named TR#some_number, for example TR7, etc.
The rule that applies to your case is TR11. Basically, you execute TR11(your_expression) to apply a trigonometric identity.
There is one small problem: whenever your perform a substitution, sympy evaluates the arguments of the expression. For example:
from sympy import *
var("x y")
expr = sin(2*x) + cos(2*x)
expr2 = expr.subs(x, y + 2)
expr2
# sin(2*y + 4) + cos(2*y + 4)

Note that 2 * (y + 2) was evaluated to 2*y + 4. The Fu module expects the arguments of the trigonometric functions to be in a specific form. TR11 expect the arguments of sin and cos to be in the form 2 * alpha, or 2 * (y + 2) in your case.
So, we need to find a way to perform that substitution without getting sympy to evaluate the expression. One solution is the somewhat controversial evaluate context manager:
with evaluate(False):
    expr2 = expr.subs(x, y+2)
    print(expr2)
# sin(2*(y + 2)) + cos(2*(y + 2))

It is controversial because it is marked as an experimental feature, meaning it can be removed from sympy anytime. Moreover, the documentation clearly states that it might not work as expected on large expressions.
Another possible solution to this problem could be UnevaluatedExpr, which keeps a specific expression from being evaluated. It works like this:
expr3 = expr.subs(x, UnevaluatedExpr(y+2))
expr3
# sin(2*(y + 2)) + cos(2*(y + 2))

However, expr is a commutative expression, while expr3 is non commutative (I suppose it is a bug), which can produce unexpected results in later operations (like differentiation, etc). That's why I'm not really a fan of this feature.
At this point, we can use the FU module:
from sympy.simplify.fu import TR11
TR11(expr2)
# -sin(y + 2)**2 + 2*sin(y + 2)*cos(y + 2) + cos(y + 2)**2

Note that TR11 applied the trigonometric identity both to the sin and cos. Should you wish to apply it only to the sin you'd have to perform some more expression manipulation:
# extract sin terms
sin_terms = expr2.find(sin)
# apply TR11 only on sin
subs_dict = {k: TR11(k) for k in sin_terms}
# substitute back
expr2.subs(subs_dict)
# 2*sin(y + 2)*cos(y + 2) + cos(2*(y + 2))


To collect the 2 in the auto-expanded 2*(x + y) you can use factor_terms:
from sympy import *
from sympy.abc import x,y
from sympy.simplify.fu import TR11

>>> sin(2*(y + 2)) + cos(2*(y + 2))
sin(2*y + 4) + cos(2*y + 4)
>>> factor_terms(_)
sin(2*(y + 2)) + cos(2*(y + 2))
>>> TR11(_)
-sin(y + 2)**2 + 2*sin(y + 2)*cos(y + 2) + cos(y + 2)**2

